# Is MarkerClusterer deprecated? What should I use instead?

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I need to implement marker clustering and found a tutorial in the official [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering), but when following the link to the [MarkerClusterer repo](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) it says its no longer maintained and kept for *historical purpose only*.

Should I use something else, or is this safe to use?

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus